# Profile Settings middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2, laravel-middleware

I have a user profile page and user profile/settings page
the problem is I made a middleware for settings page to prevent any auth user from entering other users settings page or update them Unless the ID OR SLUG IS MATCHED to the auth user but I'm using Vue whenever I use the API routes to fetch or update the data it says unauthorized 401 or 500.

middleware :

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
         if ($request->slug != auth()->user()->slug) {
            return redirect()->to('/');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

API route :

```
Route::get('/profile/{slug}','ProfilePrivateController@show')->middleware('editProfile');;
```

VueJs :

```
 update(){
            axios.put(`/api/profile/${this.id}`,{
                email : this.email,
                username : this.name,
                password : this.password,
                education_level : this.education_level,
                fb_url : this.fb_url,
                twitter_url : this.twitter_url,
                field : this.field
            })
            .then(res=>console.log(res))
        }
```

Controller :

```
 public function show($slug)
    {
         $user = User::findBySlugOrFail($slug);

         return response()->json($user);
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $slug)
    {
        $user = User::findBySlug($slug);

        $user->update([
            'email'=>$request->email,
            'education_level'=>$request->education_level,
            'field'=>$request->field,
            'school'=>$request->school,
            'fb_url'=>$request->fb_url,
            'twitter_url'=>$request->twitter_url,

        ]);
        if($request->has('password')){
            $user->save([
                'password'=>$request->password
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json('user updated',200);



    }
```

I Want to let the user update his settings and secure the API at the same time.

I'm really lost at this point Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `$request->input('slug')` ?

Comment: @vivek_23 instead of using id i used slug

Comment: I meant replace the if condition with this and check again- `if ($request->input('slug') != auth()->user()->slug) {`. Also, if this is an API you are trying to make, you should be returning a JSON response instead of redirect in middleware.

Comment: @vivek_23 how I can handle the response from the middleware in my vueApp?

Comment: For that you will have to show your controller as well.

Comment: @vivek_23 i edited the question please check

Comment: axios calls a put request `/api/profile/${this.id}`, what is an example resulting url?

Comment: You need to have a proper JSON format to send as a response.

Answer (score 1):

You have a GET request for the API route, but using a PUT request in Vue.

Updating `Route::get` to `Route::put` should solve the problem.

Also, since its an AJAX request, you should be returning a JSON response so it can easily be consumed. You can return something similar to:

```
return response()->json(['error' => 'unauthorized'], 401);
```

Comment: well i fixed the get to put .. still getting error 500